Accidently assigned my wallet to a program, now its owner is a program i dont own,Can i recover it ? I have the seed phrase and private key
Accidently assigned my wallet to a program, now its owner is a program i dont own,Can i recover it ? I have the seed phrase and private key
is it recoverable or is it hopeless ?
